# Enable Wholesale prices in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In wooCommerce, I have added a custom meta field with a custom price (wholesale price) in edit product pages settings. Everything works well.

When I set a wholesale price it works fine everywhere. But if I try to change this wholesale price it doesn't work. the old price remains everywhere.

What I am doing wrong? How can I solve this problem to allow wholesale price changes?

The code I am using:

```
function w4dev_get_wholesale_price( $product )
{
    if( 
        $product->is_type( array('simple', 'variable') ) 
        && get_post_meta( $product->id, '_wholesale_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->id, '_wholesale_price', true );
    }
    elseif( 
        $product->is_type('variation') 
        && get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_wholesale_price', true ) > 0 
    ){
        return get_post_meta( $product->variation_id, '_wholesale_price', true );
    }
    return 0;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'w4dev_woocommerce_product_options_pricing' );
function w4dev_woocommerce_product_options_pricing()
{
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id' => '_wholesale_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_wholesale_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Wholesale Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'w4dev_woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 10, 1 );
function w4dev_woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple( $product_id )
{
    if( isset($_POST['_wholesale_price']) && $_POST['_wholesale_price'] > 0 ){
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wholesale_price', $_POST['_wholesale_price'] );
        }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'w4dev_woocommerce_get_price', 10, 2);
function w4dev_woocommerce_get_price( $price, $product )
{
    if(  w4dev_get_wholesale_price($product) > 0 ) {
        $price = w4dev_get_wholesale_price($product);
    return $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some errors in your code and a lot of missing parts too:

- The hook `woocommerce_get_price` is deprecated and outdated
- To handle Product variations you need some more code (same thing for the variable products price range).
- Other errors, like when saving your Wholesale price…

Your revisited code:

```
// Add "Wholesale Price" custom field to Products option pricing
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'w4dev_add_product_options_pricing' );
function w4dev_add_product_options_pricing()
{
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_wholesale_price',
        'class' => 'wc_input_wholesale_price short',
        'label' => __( 'Wholesale Price', 'woocommerce' ) . ' ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().')',
        'type' => 'text'
    ));
}

// Add custom field to VARIATIONS option pricing
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'w4dev_add_variation_options_pricing', 20, 3 );
function w4dev_add_variation_options_pricing( $loop, $variation_data, $post_variation )
{
    $value  = get_post_meta( $post_variation->ID, '_wholesale_price', true );
    $symbol = ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')';
    $key = 'wholesale_price[' . $loop . ']';

    echo '<div class="variable_wholesale-price"><p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label>' . __( "Wholesale Price", "woocommerce" ) . $symbol . '</label>
        <input type="text" size="5" name="' . $key .'" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />
    </p></div>';
}

// Save "Wholesale Price" custom field to Products
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_simple', 'w4dev_save_product_wholesale_price', 20, 1 );
function w4dev_save_product_wholesale_price( $product_id ) {
    if( isset($_POST['_wholesale_price']) )
        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_wholesale_price', $_POST['_wholesale_price'] );
}

// Save "Wholesale Price" custom field to VARIATIONS
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'w4dev_save_product_variation_wholesale_price', 20, 2 );
function w4dev_save_product_variation_wholesale_price( $variation_id, $i ){
    if ( isset( $_POST['wholesale_price'][$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_wholesale_price', floatval( $_POST['wholesale_price'][$i] ) );
    }
}

// Simple, grouped and external products
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'w4dev_custom_price', 90, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'w4dev_custom_price', 90, 2 );

// Product variations (of a variable product)
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'w4dev_custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'w4dev_custom_price', 90, 2 );;

function w4dev_custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    if( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wholesale_price', true ) > 0 )
        $price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_wholesale_price', true );

    return $price;
}

// Variable product price ramge
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'w4dev_custom_variation_price', 90, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'w4dev_custom_variation_price', 90, 3 ); 

function w4dev_custom_variation_price( $price, $variation, $product ) {
    if( get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), '_wholesale_price', true ) > 0 )
        $price = get_post_meta( $variation->get_id(), '_wholesale_price', true );

    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

---

Now you will be able to change the value of your 'Wholesale Price' and to handle it in product variations.

**Product variations Wholesale price setting:**

[image]

---

> To handle sale prices regarding Sale prices in Woocommerce, there is those related hooks:

> - `woocommerce_product_get_sale_price`

- `woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price`
- `woocommerce_variation_prices_get_sale_price`

Comment: Can we make the Wholesale Price input attr 'disabled', ie:  add a custom attribute-  disabled = "disabled"

Comment: Got it:  'custom_attributes' => array('disabled'=>'disabled'),

Comment: @JimVanPetten Yes it's `'custom_attributes' => array('disabled' => "disabled"),` to be added in the array of the `woocommerce_wp_text_input()` function… Please if this answer was usefull for you, if you like/want you could upvote-it. thanks.